# Detecting Collinearity in hierarchical models

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am doing a glmer in R with several explaining variables (categorical and continuous), spread over 3 different levels (Level-3 = Plot, Level-2 = Distance Point, Level-1 = Sampling Number).

Before modelling, I would like to test for correlation between the variables. But I am not sure, how to include the nested structure of the model.

My idea was, to calculate the pearson-correlation between continuous variables of the same level ( with cor) and to test the pairwise relationship between the continouos variables and the categorical variables of the same level (with lm()).

But that does not account for the hierarchical structure, nor does it include correlations between the variables of different levels.

I would be grateful for any help, because I did not find a solution by myself.

Example data:

```
daten <- data.frame(plot_nr = as.factor(rep(c(1:4), each=8)),
                    distance_meter = c(rep(rep(c(80,450),each=4),4)) ,
                    sampling_number = c(as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), 8))),
                    
                    level_3_var_foresttype = c(rep(c("decidous","conifer"), each=16)),
                    level_3_var_forestarea = c(rep(c(50,32,46,13), each=8)),
                    level_3_var_elevation = c(rep(c(133,422,523,456), each=8)),
                    
                    level_2_var_vegetationhet = c(rep(c(1.4,2.5,1.56,2.1,1.8,1.6,2.4,1.3), each=4)),
                    level_2_var_distanceedge = c(rep(c(20,43,52,43,25,16,35,32), each=4)),
                    
                    level_1_var_temperature = c(rnorm(32, mean=16.3, sd=4.3)),
                    level_1_var_volume = c(rnorm(32, mean=42.3, sd=18.2)),
                    
                    count_data = c(1,0,0,2,5,0,1,5,2,2,9,3,3,6,0,0,2,3,6,1,4,6,6,4,0,0,1,2,6,3,6,2))
```

My idea was, to solve it the following way:

Correlation level 3:

```
vars_level_3 <- daten[,c(4,5,6)]
cor(vars_level_3[,-1], method="pearson") # continuous 


summary(lm(vars_level_3$level_3_var_forestarea~vars_level_3$level_3_var_foresttype)) # categorical 
summary(lm(vars_level_3$level_3_var_elevation~vars_level_3$level_3_var_foresttype)) # categorical
```

Correlation level 2:

```
vars_level_2 <- daten[,c(4,5,6,7,8)]

library(lme4)
summary(lmer(level_2_var_vegetationhet~level_2_var_distanceedge + (1|plot_nr), data=vars_level_2 ))
```

Correlation level 1:

```
vars_level_1 <- daten[,c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]


summary(lmer(level_1_var_temperature~level_1_var_volume + (1|plot_nr/sampling_number), data=vars_level_1 ))
```

But I am sure, that this is not right ...